# KVM guest can not access host using CIFS

Tags: samba, kvm-virtualization

I have a situation with a guest running on Ubuntu KVM than can't access SAMBA shares on the same host where guest is running. I would like to use samba for file sharing between host and guests.

Guest is connected to NATed network on host (default setup):

- virbr0 host IP is 192.168.122.1
- eth0 interface on guest IP 192.168.122.71

On guest:

- ssh to 192.168.122.1 - OK!
- smbclient -L192.168.122.1  -Uuser -NOT OK!
- IP traffic to any other destination from guest works OK.
- I scanned ports (nmap) form guest on (host) 192.168.122.1. Only port 22 and 53 are active.

On host:

- ssh to 192.168.122.71 - OK!
- smbclient -L192.168.122.1 -Useruser - back to host OK!

Looks like firewall problem so I configured ufw on host to allow SMB ports 137,138,139,445 (IN/OUT). No success.

Any ideas?